# Set bit X of an integer to bit Y of another integer without branching?

Tags: c++, optimization, bit-manipulation, branchless

Can the `copy_bit` function below be simplified  to something like `out[out_bit] = in[in_bit]`? (i.e. Not using an `if` statement)

```
template< typename T >
inline void copy_bit( T& out, const T in, const std::size_t out_bit, const std::size_t in_bit )
{
    if ( (in & (1 << in_bit)) != 0 )
    {
        out |= (1 << out_bit); // Set bit
    }
    else
    {
        out &= ~(1 << out_bit); // Clear bit
    }
}

// Set bit 4 in x to bit 11 in y
copy_bit( x, y, 4, 11 );
```

**Update:** Just to be clear, this isn't homework or an XY problem where suggesting `std::bitset` answers the question.

Comment: Well, we don't care for homework. We should just solve the problem for real applications.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel You are right, but I meant that part with `out[out_bit] = in[in_bit]`. Is it possible to do that 'directly'?

Comment: @Alireza: `out[out_bit] = in[in_bit]` doesn't imply that the bits must be changed directly, since in C++ you can overload `operator[]`.

Comment: not mentioned anywhere yet, but undefined behaviour is caused by `1 << in_bit` if `in_bit >= CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int)` regardless of `T`  ; consider doing `static_cast<T>(1)`, and if `T` might be signed then cast to the unsigned version of `T`

Comment: +1 for mentioning the XY problem :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can do it like that like this:

```
//Change the bit if and only if they are not equal:
out ^= (((out >> out_bit) ^ (in >> in_bit)) & 1) << out_bit;
```

(Shift both values so that the required bits are in the least significant position with >>, select with & only the lower bit of the result of the ^ operation; then shift the result into position of an otherwise zero-value to ^ with the original destination. The result is the same as copying bit in_bit of in to bit out_bit of out.)

Comment: bonus points if you can profile this and compare with the original code (it's hard to see why OP makes this request unless he thinks he can outdo his compiler for performance gains)

Comment: I did the hard part, let someone else do the profiling (:  . Anyway the request was to simplify the code not to optimize it.

Comment: Am not sure a lot of people would consider this more "simple" than the original code :)

Answer (score 6):

One way to do so in one line would be to first reset the output bit to zero, and then OR it with whatever bit the `in` number has:

```
(out &= ~(1 << out_bit)) |= (((in >> in_bit) & 1) << out_bit)
```

Comment: Too many compound assignment operators; it's very hard to prove whether this has undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes, I myself get confused with sequence points. I believe my answer might indeed have undefined behavior.

Comment: in C++03 it surely has undefined behaviour (two assignments to same variable without intervening sequence point) although this is easily fixed by not using the compound assignment

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
template< typename T >
inline void copy_bit( T& out, const T in, const std::size_t out_bit, const std::size_t in_bit )
{
    out = (out & ~(1 << out_bit)) | (((in & (1 << in_bit)) >> in_bit) << out_bit);
}
```

Explanation:

- `(out & ~(1 << out_bit))` leave the bits of `out` that aren't interesting.
- `(in & (1 << in_bit)` select the bit of `in` that is interesting
- `(((in & (1 << in_bit)) >> in_bit) << out_bit)` positionate the bit in the correct position.

Comment: Good explanation, but `(((in & (1 << in_bit)) >> in_bit) << out_bit)` could be simplified to `(((in >> in_bit) & 1) << out_bit)`, saves a shift.